# Qual a origem da palavra "toa" usada na expressão "à toa"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem

Não cheguei a consultar nenhum corpus linguístico mas imagino que a palavra "toa", isolada, seja usada muito raramente. Já a expressão "à toa", de uso frequente, parece ter significados diversos dependendo do contexto.

> - "brigaram por **uma coisa à toa**" (por uma bobagem)
> - "**não é à toa** que ele é tão criticado" (não é sem motivo)
> - "resolvi aparar a grama só pra não **ficar à toa**" (desocupado, sem ter o que fazer)
> - "estava **à toa na vida**, o meu amor me chamou, pra ver a banda passar..." (desocupado)
> - "todo mundo sabe que ela é **uma mulher à toa**" (uma vagabunda)

Por que "à toa"?  Qual a origem da expressão?

Comment: @Jacinto  Não me parece haver o acento circunflexo no "porque" da frase acima.   http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/uso-dos-porques/

Comment: *Porque* é que não pode ser: [*porque* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/porque) é apenas conjunção (*fi-lo porque qui-lo*); é assim também nos exemplos do Infoescola. Agora, pelos vistos no Brasil é *por quê* (em Portugal é pegado). O Infoescola não tem nenhum exemplo da tua construção. Para mim é o mesmo *por quê* do fim de frase. Quando muito poderia ser *por que*, mas não creio: eu escrevo  *por quê/porquê* porque é assim que pronuncio; em Portugal *por quê/porquê* pronuncia-se diferentemente de *por que/porque*.

Comment: Temos finalmente  [a resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%C3%A3-por-qu%C3%AA-amanh%C3%A3-ou-por-que-amanh%C3%A3-em-portugu%C3%AAs-bra): é *por que "à toa"?* na norma brasileira, mas *porquê "à toa"?* na norma europeia.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Há uma boa razão para desconhecermos a palavra ***toa*** fora da expressão *à toa*: quem imaginaria que uma [***toa*** (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/toa%20_1055830.html) fosse um cabo para rebocar embarcações? A locução ***à toa*** começou por significar, falando-se de embarcações, «à mercê de toa (‘cabo’); sem atividade própria» (Houaiss), e é neste sentido comum até ao século XVII. A partir deste, surgem por extensão os outros sentidos: ao acaso, irrefletidamente, sem motivo.

A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei de *à toa* foi em [Fernão Lopes, *Crónica de Dom João I*, 1443](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_de_el-rei_D._Jo%C3%A3o_I), tal como aparece no [Corpus Informatizado do Português Mediaval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) (registo necessário; ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> e porque a maree vazava e o vemto era calmo, levavom as gallees as naaos gramdes ***aa toya***;

O exemplo seguinte, numa grafia mais próxima da atual, é da *Crónica do Conde D. Pedro de Meneses* de [Gomes Eanes de Zurara (1410-74):](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomes_Eanes_de_Zurara)

> não passou gramde espaço quamdo vyram sahyr de Larache [em Marrocos] hûa vella. & Allvaro Fernamdez vogou a ella & filhou-ha, & hera hû carevo, em que tomarã tres mouros, & muita louça de Mallaga, & pano, & outra mercadoria. E em tornamdo-se pera domde partyrã, queremdo surgir outra vez, virã como a fumdo de Larache amdava hûa barca. &, leyxamdo ho carevo surto sobre ferro, vogarão a barca, a qual trazia hû carevo ***a toa*** comsygo carregado de fruita & çimco mouros em elle

Aqui um exemplo mais claro de [*A Peregrinação* de Fernão Mendes Pinto (1510/14-1583)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peregrina%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(livro)):

> O nosso batel chegou com muyta pressa à embarcação que tinhamos visto, & sem nenhua difficuldade a trouxe ***á toa***

Uma embarcação que vai à toa (rebocada por outra) não se governa por si mesma. Daqui ***à toa*** parece ter adquirido o significado de “à deriva”, como encontramos na [*Gazeta de Lisboa ocidental* de 1724:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=U0xTAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&dq=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDlfrv88rMAhWIPRoKHdT4C2M4ChDoAQghMAE)

> e o mandaraõ para esta Cidade com huma embarcação Hespanhola carregada de vinhos, que acharaõ no mar ***à toa***, sem gente alguma.

E também nesta [*Relaçam do monstruoso peixe que nas prayas do Tejo appareceo em 16 de Mayo deste presente anno de 1748*:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Ew9XAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP3&dq=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDlfrv88rMAhWIPRoKHdT4C2M4ChDoAQg3MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&f=false)

> neste tempo os da canoa se vaõ cehagando a ella , e com huns grandes ferros em humas varas metidos, e para este ministerio preparados, pelas partes mais sensitivas a vaõ picando , até que derramado muito sangue, e por falta delle debilitadas as forças , a Balea ***á toa*** sobre a agua , e vendose que está morta , chegaõ os barcos , e lhe passam hum cabo , pelo qual a conduzem ao porto.

Uma pessoa que vai figuradamente ***à toa*** não sabe para onde vai. Esta é a interpretação de [Domingo Vieira, *Thesouro da lingua portugueza*, 1871](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6MdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA642&dq=%22a%20toa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4rc615srMAhUBiRoKHUM7AUAQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20toa%22&f=false), que cita [Paiva de Andrade (1528-75)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_de_Paiva_de_Andrade), fornecendo assim o primeiro uso figurativo que consegui encontrar de *à toa*:

> **Á TOA**, *loc. adv.* (Da preposição « á », e do substantivo tôa, corda, sirga de reboque.) A reboque, á sirga, a rastos; figuradamente, ir sem saber para onde é levado; obrar impensadamente. ― «*Coitados dos que trazeis atados os peccados com razões apparentes, falsas e vãas, que os trazeis **á tôa**, como as cordas por onde o carro se governa*.» Paaiva de Andrade, Sermões, Part. I, fol. 87 v.

Encontrei outro uso figurado temporão  em [Fernão Cardim](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern%C3%A3o_Cardim), *Carta de relação da viagem e missão a Província do Brasil*, 1590:

> Estava já neste tempo o nosso navio fora da barra, e, por o tempo ser algum tanto contrário para sair, andámos até alta noite aos bordos, não podendo tomar o navio, e quando o tomámos foi ***à toa*** cair o padre Rodrigo de Freitas ao mar, entre o navio e barca, donde o tirámos meio afogado, mais foi Nosso Senhor servido que não chegasse o desastre a mais.

Depois do século XVII, a locução *à toa* rareia no registo escrito, e reaparece em força no século XIX, sobretudo em autores brasileiros, mas agora nos sentidos figurados modernos. Muitos destes sentidos eram no entanto já correntes na língua oral em meados do século XVIII, pois em 1759 Manuel José de Paiva inclui *à toa* e *falar à toa* nas *Infermidades da Lingua, e a Arte que Ensina a Emmudecer para Melhorar*, integrados numa extensíssima lista de expressões, muitas das quais populares ainda hoje, que o autor aconselha a evitar.

O sentido original de *à toa*, “a reboque”, parece a certa altura nos séculos XVII ou XVIII ter caído no esquecimento, de tal forma que encontramos no início do século XIX dois dicionários com ideias disparatadas acerca da origem da locução. Um acha que *à toa* é uma metáfora musical; outro, que vem de *perturbação* em árabe:

> ***Tôa*** ‚ alavra introduzida para signifcar cousa , que se governa ‚ ou deixa levar sem sciencia, nem industria: v. g. ir o navio ***á Tôa***, he ir para onde o leva a agoa. Ir ***á Tôa***, ir sem saber para onde. Parece-me раlavrа dimìnutiva de Toáda , ou derivada de Tom , como metaphora de músico, que não sabe , mas segue o tom que ouve. [[João de Moraes Madureira Feijó, *Orthographia ou arte de escrever e pronunciar com acerto a Lingua Portugueza*, 1815.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PZxWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA460&dq=%22a%20toa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ9OKd4MrMAhWQyRoKHVFMDzA4ChDoAQhQMAk#v=onepage&q=%22a%20toa%22&f=false)
>
> **Toa** [carateres árabes] *Tuha*. Perturbação. Diriva-se do verbo [carateres árabes] *Taha*. Andar errante , vagando. Hir ***á toa***, i. e. sem saber por onde se vai, talvez conduzido por outro; andar ***á toa*** , i. e. sem saber por onde anda , sem saber o que faz : levar o navio ***á toa***, i. e. guiar , e puxar com huma corda o navio, que não governa. [[João de Sousa, *Vestigios da Lingoa Arabica em Portugal*, 1830.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RuhGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA193&dq=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI3L3F-8rMAhUDfhoKHY9NBz8Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A1%20toa%22&f=false)

Comment: Interessante. Conhecia _tow_, mas em português acho que ouvi sempre _rebocar_ em vez de _atoar_.

Comment: @Artefacto O Houaiss diz que *toa* é regressivo de *toar*, mas eu não encontro *toar* ou *atoar* em lado nenhum. E para encontrar *à toa* no sentido original tens que ir aos autores quinhentistas.

Comment: _atoar_ está no Aulete, Priberam, Michaelis. _toar_ não está com este sentido.

Comment: @Artefacto Encontro nos dicionários; não encontro é uso espontâneo.

Comment: Aqui em sentido figurado: https://books.google.nl/books?id=6jImXbHLghsC&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=%22dizeis+que+o+amor+fino+como+mel%C3%A3o+n%C3%A3o+h%C3%A1-de+querer%22&source=bl&ots=mmfkrqsxWk&sig=ml_pm_yDAkewy7bmtvUSmXrVLhE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=atoado&f=false

Comment: @Artefacto Interessante: isso aparece para aí um século depois de *à toa* deixar de ser usado como *a reboque* ou ligado a *amarrar*.

Comment: Respostas completas como esta, com fontes e referências, engrandecem o site de língua portuguesa.

Comment: @Centaurus Obrigado. Antes da resposta teve que haver a pergunta. Acho que nunca tinha pensado neste assunto.

Comment: @Jacinto A passagem é de Camões. Século XVI portanto. A edição é que é mais tardia.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre considerei que o sentido actual de 'à toa' também se inspire no adjetivo tola (ô, semiaberto), cuja origem etimológica é obscura mas pode ter a ver com o substantivo tola (ó, aberto) que significa cabeça. Uma tolice, uma ideia tola, sempre a significar sem sentido, irreflectido, uma patetice...

Talvez o cabo da embarcação tenha ganho primeiro esse sentido (sem rumo, ao sabor das vagas) e depois essa nova morfologia, pela interposição do 'l', e o termo original toa fosse recuperado posteriormente para ser uma alternativa de tola-adjectivo.