# «Vais embora amanhã?!» — «Por quê amanhã?» ou «por que amanhã?» em português brasileiro?

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe

Esta dúvida surgiu-me nesta pergunta sobre [*à toa*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/qual-a-origem-da-palavra-toa-usada-na-express%C3%A3o-%C3%A0-toa) e nesta sobre [*punheta de bacalhau*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/punheta-de-bacalhau-porqu%C3%AA-punheta-qual-a-origem). Nas perguntas originais perguntava-se ***porque à toa?*** e ***porque punheta?***, e eu fui todo lampeiro e mudei o ***porque*** para ***porquê***. Este ***porquê*** é norma europeia, e corresponde ao ***por quê*** da norma brasileira (que era o que eu deveria ter usado, porque a pergunta está em português brasileiro).

O autor da pergunta chamou-me a atenção para o [infoescola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/uso-dos-porques/), que diz que ***por quê*** só se usa no final de frases. O [Brasilescola](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/por-que.htm) e o [educação.uol](http://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/por-que-porque-por-que-ou-porque-o-uso-correto-segundo-a-gramatica.htm) dizem a mesma coisa. Mas eu tenho a certeza que em Portugal se diz ***porquê amanhã*** (grafado *por quê* no Brasil), jamais *porque* ou *por que*. Não é apenas uma questão de se escrever; é de se dizer. Em Portugal, *porquê* é pronunciado como no Brasil, mas *porque* e *por que* são pronunciados /purk/.

Nós temos esta [pergunta sobre *porque, por que, porquê* e *por quê*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA), mas as respostas que lá estão não esclarecem este caso concreto. Sistematizemos o problema. As frases seguintes são pacíficas, pois *por quê/porquê* aparecem no fim da frase.

> (a) ptBR: Vais embora amanhã ***por quê***? (ptPT: *porquê*.)
>
> (b) ptBR: Vais embora amanhã? ***Amanhã por quê?*** (ptPT: *porquê*.)

A frase seguinte é padrão em Portugal e parece-me equivalente à (b), mas parece violar as instruções dos sites acima:

> (c) ptPT: Vais embora amanhã? ***Porquê amanhã?*** (Deveria dar *por quê amanhã* em ptBR.)

É verdade que os sites indicados não me inspiram completa confiança. Eles não esclarecem bem a sintaxe; parecem mais dar truques para se saber quando se põe ou não o acento circunflexo. Por outro lado eu pergunto-me se a diferença entre português europeu e brasileiro neste caso se limita à grafia e pronúncia, ou se é mesmo uma diferença de sintaxe. As frases *amanhã porquê?* e *porquê amanhã* parecem incompletas; dão a ideia de ter sofrido uma elipse qualquer. Por exemplo poderíamos justificar *por que amanhã* (ptBR; ptPT *porque*) com uma elisão do ***é*** em *por que é amanhã?* E por mais outro lado, em Portugal diz-se *porquê amanhã?*, mas *porque não amanhã?*

Resumindo, em Portugal é ***porquê amanhã*** porque é *porquê* que corresponde à pronúncia. E as perguntas são:

- A grafia correta no Brasil é ***por quê amanhã?*** ou ***por que amanhã?***
- Como no português brasileiro —segundo julgo saber— *por quê* e *por que* são pronunciados da mesma maneira, qual é a justificação da escolha?

Comment: Isso parece-me simplesmente confusão dos brasileiros por dizerem da mesma maneira. Se levarmos essa de estar no fim à letra chegamos à conclusão de que seria _Por que amanhã?_ mas _Amanhã por quê?_. _Por que amanhã?_ só se _amanhã_ fosse nome (tipo _por que amanhã lutamos nós?_)

Comment: Por que (pergunta), porque (resposta), o porquê (substantivado), Por quê (neste caso o 'quê' por estar no fim da frase é acentuado, assim como em O quê? O que foi isso?)

Comment: "Vais embora amanhã", isso é típico de Portugal. No Brasil não falamos assim também! (apesar de não estar errado)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Porquê" é um substantivo: *Posso saber qual o **porquê** de Vossa Senhoria estar chegando às três da madrugada?* Como o "porquê" na sua frase certamente não é um substantivo, * "Porquê amanhã?" está incorreto.

"Porque" é uma conjunção explicativa: *Estou chegando às três da madrugada **porque** quero*. *Vou amanhã **porque** tenho pressa*. Então geralmente não se usa em perguntas, e certamente não no seu exemplo, onde claramente não é uma conjunção explicativa.

"Por que" e "por quê" são locuções equivalentes a "por/pelo/pela qual" ou "por qual motivo": *A razão **por que** estou chegando às três da madrugada com certeza não é da conta de Vossa Excelência*. Usa-se a forma acentuada no final da frase, acompanhando a prosódia da língua falada (na qual o "que" no meio ou início de frase é bem átono, enquanto a tônica no "quê" é bem marcada no final): *Estou chegando às três da madrugada porque posso, **por quê***? Da mesma forma, ***Por que*** amanhã? = "Por qual motivo amanhã?": separado e sem acento. E *Amanhã, **por quê**?* = "Amanhã, por qual motivo?": separado e com acento.

---

Você diz que "Porquê amanhã" é regra europeia, e me deixa curioso, porque (=pois, então junto e sem acento) minha impressão sobre a norma brasileira é que, tirando a grafia de certas palavras, se trata de cópia servil da norma europeia, muitas vezes sem atentar para a realidade da língua local ("Dê-me"?! isso pode ser bom para quem pronuncia "dem", mas não funciona para quem pronuncia "deme").

Comment: Fiquei esclarecido! Em Portugal, *porquê* além de substantivo é advérbio interrogativo equivalente ao *por quê* da norma brasileira. E *porque*, em Portugal, além de conjunção é também advérbio interrogativo. Basicamente o *por que* da norma brasileira grafa-se em Portugal também separado se o *por que* for substituível por *por/pelo/pela qual* (*a razão por que estou* = *a razão pela qual estou*; *por que motivo fizeste isso* = *por qual motivo*...) mas grafa-se *porque* caso contrário, quando o *por que* brasileiro equivale a *por que motivo* (em Portugal, *porque fizeste isso?*).

Comment: No português europeu também há diferença de prosódia entre *porquê amanhã?* e o *amanhã porquê?*, mas há uma diferença também entre a pronúncia do *porque* e do *porquê*: *porquê* é pronunciado **pur.'kê**, como no Brasil (sílaba tónica no *quê*), enquanto *porque* é pronunciado **ˈpur.k(ə)**, (sílaba tónica em *por*) e em que o **ə** é aquele *e* quase ou completamente inaudível dos portugueses. Por isso em Portugal escreve-se *porquê amanhã?* porque nestes caso pronunciamos *pur'kê*.

Comment: Bem explicado.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

PT-BR

POR QUE

```
A forma por que é a sequência de uma preposição (por) e um pronome interrogativo (que). Equivale a "por qual razão", "por qual motivo":

Exemplos:
    Desejo saber por que você voltou tão tarde para casa.
    Por que você comprou este casaco?

Há casos em que por que representa a sequência preposição + pronome relativo, equivalendo a "pelo qual" (ou alguma de suas flexões (pela qual, pelos quais, pelas quais).

Exemplos:
    Estes são os direitos por que estamos lutando.
    O túnel por que passamos existe há muitos anos.
```

POR QUÊ

```
Caso surja no final de uma frase, imediatamente antes de um ponto (final, de interrogação, de exclamação) ou de reticências, a sequência deve ser grafada por quê, pois, devido à posição na frase, o monossílabo "que" passa a ser tônico.

Exemplos:
    Estudei bastante ontem à noite. Sabe por quê?
    Será deselegante se você perguntar novamente por quê!
```

PORQUE

```
A forma porque é uma conjunção, equivalendo a pois, já que, uma vez que, como. Costuma ser utilizado em respostas, para explicação ou causa.

Exemplos:
    Vou ao supermercado porque não temos mais frutas.
    Você veio até aqui porque não conseguiu telefonar?
```

PORQUÊ

```
A forma porquê representa um substantivo. Significa "causa", "razão", "motivo" e normalmente surge acompanhada de palavra determinante (artigo, por exemplo).

Exemplos:
    Não consigo entender o porquê de sua ausência.
    Existem muitos porquês para justificar esta atitude.
    Você não vai à festa? Diga-me ao menos um porquê.
```

Fonte: [So Portugues](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono26.php)

Comment: Esta resposta é um simples copy & paste do site, que não difere dos sites já referidos na pergunta, e não responde à pergunta. A pergunta é sobre frases do tipo *por que/por quê amanhã*, isto é *por que/por quê* seguido de frase sem verbo conjugado. A tua resposta, ou melhor o site, não cobre este tipo de frase.

Comment: Os porquês escritos de formas diferentes são para diferenciação. O 'que' acentuado no final da frase é por tornar-se tônico e não é exclusividade dos porquês. Está na resposta acima.

Comment: Então, você pergunta se 'Por que amanhã?' é acentuado? Não, pois o quê está tônico? Queriam dizer: 'Por quê? Amanhã?'. Não está claro o problema pois mesmo os sites errando a regra do 'que' acentuado, dá pra entender que isso ocorre só em fim de frases ou orações.

Comment: Portanto, _tomas o que com os teus cereais?_? Não está no fim de uma frase.

Comment: Sua frase é sem acento, o 'que' não é tônico, nem é substantivo. Sua frase com acento 'Portanto, tomas os teus cereais com o quê?'

Comment: Que curioso. Em pt-PT, essa frase é sempre com quê: "tomas o quê com os teus cereais?", e "tomas os teus cereais com quê?". Esta pergunta levanta questões bem interessantes...