# Uso dos porquês: Junto, com acento mas como conjunção explicativa

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia

Uma dúvida que tive recentemente. Existem quatro porquês na língua portuguesa, conforme explicado [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/porque-porque-por-que-ou-por-que/). Vejo que o "por quê" leva acento circunflexo justamente por estar antes de pontuação, e que o "porquê" é um substantivo, que tem mesmo sentido de "motivo". Mas na seguinte situação:

> O exército do Rei Vermelho  não conseguiu vencer a batalha porque:
>
> 1. O exército inimigo era mais forte.
> 2. As tropas aliadas não conseguiram ajudar a tempo.

Eu estou usando um "porque" de conjunção explicativa, porém vindo logo antes de pontuação (Dois pontos). Pela mesma lógica do acento do "por quê" ser devido a preceder pontuação, não deveria ser o caso desse "porque" usado ser junto e com acento, porém sendo uma conjunção explicativa?

Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo @dude3221! Podes citar textualmente sua frase com _porque_ de conjunção explicativa logo antes da pontuação? Vai ajudar a obteres melhores respostas!

Comment: Obrigado. Não cheguei a ver em texto algum, era um exemplo genérico de situação. Mas inventei um contexto agora, talvez deixe mais claro.

Comment: Curiosidade: em pt-PT, aquele quarto "por quê" não existe; ver https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%c3%a3-por-qu%c3%aa-amanh%c3%a3-ou-por-que-amanh%c3%a3-em-portugu%c3%aas-bra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você parta de uma premissa equivocada que acabou por levá-lo a uma conclusão também inexata:

> [...] Pela mesma lógica do acento do "por quê" ser devido a preceder
> pontuação [...]

O `por quê` utilizado no fim da frase não é devido a preceder pontuação, mas sim pela sentença ter caráter interrogativo e a conjunção explicativa aparecer no final dela. O próprio texto do link apresentado por você diz isso de maneira clara:

> Quando usar por quê?
>
> Por quê (separado e com acento) é usado em interrogações. Aparece sempre no final da frase, seguido de ponto de interrogação ou de um ponto final.

O exemplo oferecido por você não tem caráter interrogativo, mas afirmativo; além disso, apesar de visualmente parecer terminar nos `:`, na verdade, semanticamente, é concluído após cada um dos complementos dados:

> O exército do Rei Vermelho não conseguiu vencer a batalha porque **o
> exército inimigo era mais forte**.
>
> O exército do Rei Vermelho não conseguiu vencer a batalha porque **as
> tropas aliadas não conseguiram ajudar a tempo**.

Comment: Mas e na frase "Não sei por quê." há caráter interrogativo? Sempre pensei que fosse por causa do ponto...

Comment: Faça uma substituição simples de `por quê` por `por qual motivo`, tanto no exemplo de sua pergunta principal quanto nesta última, e veja qual delas ainda faz sentido. Seu último exemplo tem caráter interrogativo, há uma pergunta implícita, ao passo que no seu primeiro exemplo, não.

Comment: Entendi. Grato.

Comment: Então, no Brasil, em resposta a "obrigado" é "não tem de quê" ou "não tem de que"? Em Portugal é "não tem de quê"; mas como aqui "que" e "quê" são pronunciados de forma muito diferente, nós não temos que nos preocupar se a frase tem caráter interrogativo ou não.

Comment: @Jacinto O correto é "Não tem de quê." (apenas no uso informal), na norma culta utiliza-se "Não há de quê." devido o termo `há` ser verbo impessoal (e não há sujeito)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Curiosa essa distinção entre "não tem de quê" informal e "não há de quê" culto. Aqui em Portugal só se diz "não tem de quê"; mas é pessoal: está implícito "você" ou "o senhor"; "(você/o senhor) não tem de quê". No tratamento por tu dizemos "não tens de quê". Nós nem usamos "ter" impessoal para indicar existência, só "haver".