# A expressão "por quê" se encaixa em qual classe gramatical?

Tags: morfologia, classificação-de-palavras

Sabe se que:
O "porque" é uma conjunção causal;
O "porquê" é um substantivo;
E o "por que" um advérbio interrogativo de causa.
Qual seria entâo a classe do "por quê"?
Peço que me respondam e me corrijam caso o desenvolvimento da pergunta conter algum erro.

Comment: até onde eu sei, a diferença de *por que* e *por quê* é quando é escrito no final da frase ou não (com acento é quando é no final da frase). Nesse caso, seria também um advérbio interrogativo de causa

Comment: M. Melo, *por quê* é advérbio interrogativo, tal como o *por que* (a única diferença entre os dois é que *por quê* ocorre no fim da frase e é acentuado por causa da prosódia diferente). Já existe [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/como-usar-corretamente-por-que-por-qu%C3%AA-porque-ou-porqu%C3%AA) sobre *porque, por que, por quê, porquê*. O foco dela está nos diferentes usos e não na classificação gramatical, mas talvez responda à tua dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

A análise é a mesma que com a forma não tónica *por que*. Repara que não há diferença entre estas duas frases:

- O João fez isso **por quê**?
- **Por que** fez isso o João? / **Por que** é que o João fez isso?

*Quê* na locução proposicional *por quê* é um pronome, nomeadamente um pronome interrogativo:

- O João fez isso, mas não sabe **por quê**.
- O João luta **por quê**? (*por que coisas* ou *por que razão*)

Dado que *quê* só pode aparecer no final de uma oração ou, em português europeu pelo menos, em frases sem verbo finito (*Para quê fazer isso?*), não me parece que *quê* possa alguma vez ser um pronome relativo (mas se ocorrer a alguém um exemplo, um comentário é bem-vindo).

(Quando *por* designa causa, em português europeu também se faz a justaposição e *por que* e *por quê* tansformam-se em *porque* e *porquê*. Ignorei este detalhe.)

Comment: Não tenho é a certeza de se grafar *para quê fazer isso?* no Brasil. A resposta a esta [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%C3%A3-por-qu%C3%AA-amanh%C3%A3-ou-por-que-amanh%C3%A3-em-portugu%C3%AAs-bra?noredirect=1&lq=1) diz que no Brasil é *por que amanhã?*, o que me leva a crer que seja também *para que fazer isso?*

Comment: @Jacinto corrigido então

Answer (score 1):

Só para completare e corrigir um detalhe.
O  (por que) separado sem acento usa-se quando perguntamos por qual "motivo".
O (por quê) separado e com acento usa-se quando está no final da ESTRUTURA e não no final da frase ou período ou seja, no final de uma oração. se houver uma estrutura intercalada não se utiliza o (por quê) acentuado.

ex Não sei por quê, mas ele não respondeu. (não sei por qual motivo) fim da estrutura.
Não sei por que, ontem, ele não estava bem. (não sei por qual motivo) meio da estrutura.
O porquê junto e com acento, usa-se quando o termo esta substantivado, por um artigo ou pronome.
ex Vamos aprender o uso dos porquês (preposição de + os) substantivo.

O porque junto sem acento usa-se para responder, causa ou explicação. Oração subordinada adverbial de causa ou oração coordenada explicativa. pode ser trocado por (pois)

e ainda tem o (por que) separado sem acento que é um pronome relativo.
ex Este é o cargo por que luto. (o POR é preposição exigida pelo verbo lutar e o que é pron relativo retoma cargo).

Answer (score 0):

Seria um pronome relativo o **por quê** com acento.

> Por que
>
> Pode ser a junção da preposição por com o pronome relativo que ou com
>   o pronome interrogativo que, assumindo assim dois empregos diferentes.
>   Sendo pronome interrogativo significa: por qual motivo, por qual
>   razão. Sendo pronome relativo significa: por qual ou pelo qual.(separado e sem acento) se utiliza no meio das frases.
>
> Por quê 
>   (separado e com acento) é utilizado apenas final da
>   oração, seguido de um sinal de pontuação. É a junção da preposição por
>   com o pronome interrogativo tônico quê. Significa por qual motivo, por
>   qual razão. O pronome quê também é tônico e acentuado nas expressões
>   de quê e para quê.

Fonte: [Dúvidas de Português](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/por-que-por-que-porque-porque/)

Comment: Neste exemplo "Não foi a festa por quê?" me parece que o "por quê" tem o sentido circunstância de causa (a causa por que não foi à festa). Se fosse pronome relativo teria que se referir a algum nome ou pronome.

Answer (score 0):

"Por que" no início, meio ou final da frase é a mesma conjunção adverbial: "por qual razão" ou "por qual motivo". Porém, quando o pronome "que" aparece no final da frase, ele sempre deve ser acentuado para marcá-lo como monossílabo tônico.
Outros exemplos onde o pronome "que" é acentuado ao final da frase:

- Fazer o quê?
- O quê?
- Pelo o quê?