# O que significa "estar à toa"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

O que significa **estar à toa**? Eu sei que isso é sinônimo de "**estar desocupado**"?

[Aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/qual-a-origem-da-palavra-toa-usada-na-express%C3%A3o-%C3%A0-toa) eu já vi "à toa". Mas não entendi o que significa "estar à toa".

Procurando na Internet eu achei que estar à toa talvez significa **tem nada para fazer**!

Isso é certo?

O que é **toa**?

Comment: Estar a toá, é estar de vadiagem (http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/estar%20%C3%A0%20toa/). Tbm pode ser "estar sem fazer nada" Acho que tu deves quebrar a tua pergunta em duas perguntas.São coisas totalmente diferentes Estar a toá e a pergunta sobre despedir-se.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qual a origem da palavra "toa" usada na expressão "à toa"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/qual-a-origem-da-palavra-toa-usada-na-express%c3%a3o-%c3%a0-toa)

Comment: @Peixoto, não acho que seja uma duplicata. Naquela pergunta, o autor já sabe o que a expressão significa, e só pede o significado duma palavra específica que a compõe. Nesta, o autor desconhece o significado da expressão idiomática por inteiro e pergunta qual é. E como as respostas de lá são bem específicas e usam um vocabulário português pesado, acho que não é o adequado para alguém que está a aprender o idioma (como me parece ser o caso de Majid).

Comment: @Peixoto Você tem razão! Eu já tinha visto  “à toa”. Mas entendi nada! por isso eu perguntei aqui.

Comment: @Peixoto Então "estar sem fazer nada" significa alguma coiza negativo?

Quer dizer desemprego?  Ou só não gostaria de fazer nada por isso "Estar sem fazer nada"?

Comment: Não usamos à toa para significar sem trabalho. Mas para uma situação momentânea. Pode significar algo negativo...

Comment: Obrigada @Peixoto Acho que entendi! Poderia, por favor, escrever uma resposta?

Comment: Majid, tanto na pergunta, quanto na resposta, da pergunta ["Qual a origem da expressão à toa"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/qual-a-origem-da-palavra-toa-usada-na-express%c3%a3o-%c3%a0-toa) você encontra todos os significados da expressão e exemplos em frases.

Comment: O certo é à toa. Significa "sem nada para fazer". Mas curiosamente "toa" não tem nenhum significado e não tem nenhum outro uso corrente fora dessa expressão.

Comment: @mguima   Na resposta à pergunta [**"qual a origem da expressão à toa"**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/qual-a-origem-da-palavra-toa-usada-na-express%C3%A3o-%C3%A0-toa) Jacinto faz uma excelente dissertação sobre a origem e o significado da palavra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O termo "estar á toa" significa não ter nada importante para fazer.

Comment: Sheila, bem-vindo ao site! Porém, neste site tentamos usar referências para fortalecer o argumento, pois, a força possuída quando não há referência é absurdamente pequena se se comparar a quando com referência.